# get param value to generate a chart

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, httpresponse

user enter two date
it need to click on a button...

if the date are valid, the same jsp page is called and some value are setted in the request... in this jsp, if setSeachDone is true, a chart is generate...

another servled controller is called for the image... but the value already setted in the request are empty

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/statError")
public class StatisticError {

@Autowired
private IUserService userService;

@InitBinder("statisticForm")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new StatisticErrorFormValidator());
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String statistic(Model model) {
    StatisticErrorForm statisticForm = new StatisticErrorForm();
    model.addAttribute("statisticForm", statisticForm);
    return "statisticError";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String statistiqueResult(@Valid @ModelAttribute StatisticErrorForm statisticForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (!result.hasFieldErrors() && !result.hasErrors()) {

        request.setAttribute("startDate", statisticForm.getStartDate());
        request.setAttribute("endDate", statisticForm.getEndDate());
        statisticForm.setSearchDone(true);
    }

    model.addAttribute(statisticForm);

    return "statisticError";
}
```

}

the servlet controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/statError.jpg")
public class ImageErrorController {

@Autowired
private IUserService userService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void generateChart(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
   if (request.getAttribute("startDate") != null && request.getAttribute("endDate") != null) {

      response.setContentType("image/jpg");
      AxisChart axisChart = userService.generateChart();
      ServletEncoderHelper.encodeJPEG(axisChart, 1.0f, response);

    }
```

}

is there a way to send the value entered by the user to the imageErrorController?
add the model to generateChart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass them as parameters of image URL in your view, like this:

```
<img src = "<c:url value = "/statError.jpg">
        <c:param name = "startDate" value = "${startDate}" />
        <c:param name = "endDate" value = "${endDate}" />
    </c:url>" />
```

Comment: ok i tried that, but request.getAttribute("startDate") continue to be null